# How to write a byte form input to output files?

Tags: c++, c++11, io, ifstream, ofstream

I am trying to write a tester for a function that takes writes info bit by bit from one file to another. I am pretty sure that my BitOutputStream class works since the code below prints out an 'A' as expected. But when I change the code to the second version below that takes the input file and writes the output file the input does not match the output. I am not sure if I am inadvertently changing something I shouldn't or the input file has certain "hidden" characters that cause the mismatch or byte shifting to occur.  I suspect I might not be using get() correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

/*  first (working) version */

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  BitOutputStream bos(std::cout);  // channel output to stdout
  bos.writeBit(1);
  bos.writeBit(0);
  bos.writeBit(0);
  bos.writeBit(0);
  bos.writeBit(0);
  bos.writeBit(0);
  bos.writeBit(0);
  bos.writeBit(1);

  // prints an 'A' as expected

  return 0;
}
```

/* second (non-working) version */

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::string ifileName = std::string(argv[1]);
  std::string ofileName = std::string(argv[2]);

  ofstream ofile;
  ifstream ifile;

  if(ifile)
    ifile.open(ifileName, ios::binary);
  if(ofile)
    ofile.open(ofileName, ios::binary);

  BitOutputStream bos(ofile);

  int i;
  while (ifile.good()) { 
    i = bos.writeBit(ifile.get()); // could the error be due to incorrect usage of get()?
    std::cout << i << std::endl;  // just to see how many bits have been processed
  }

    bos.flush();

    ifile.close();
    ofile.close();

    return i;
 }
```

The first version I call with

```
./a.out
```

The second version I call with

```
./a.out input output
```

which prints 
1
2 
3
to the terminal indication writeBit was called three times but I expected it to be called 8 times for 'A', so why 3 times only?

input file has just 'A' in it.
calling hexdump on input file generates:

```
0000000 0a41
0000002
```

calling hexdump on output file generates:

```
0000000 0005
0000001
```

Also why does hexdump generate 7 0's before 0a-'linefeed' and 41-'A' and what is the meaning of '0000002' at the end? What can I change in the second version of the code so the hexdump for input and output match?

EDIT: here is the declaration/definition for BitOutputStream

```
#ifndef BITOUTPUTSTREAM_HPP
#define BITOUTPUTSTREAM_HPP
#include <iostream>

class BitOutputStream {

private: 
  char buf;             // one byte buffer of bits
  int nbits;            // how many bits have been written to buf
  std::ostream& out;    // reference to the output stream to use

public:
  /* Initialize a BitOutputStream that will 
   * use the given ostream for output. 
   * */
  BitOutputStream(std::ostream& os) : out(os) {
    buf = nbits = 0;    // clear buffer and bit counter
  }

  /* Send the buffer to the output, and clear it */
  void flush() {
  out.put(buf);
  buf = nbits = 0;
  }


  /* Write the least sig bit of arg into buffer */
  int writeBit(int i) {
  // If bit buffer is full, flush it.
  if (nbits == 8) 
    flush();

  int lb = i & 1;      // extract the lowest bit
  buf |= lb << nbits;  // shift it nbits and put in in buf

  // increment index
  nbits++;

  return nbits;
  }
};

#endif // BITOUTPUTSTREAM_HPP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the concept of bits vs. bytes.  A byte, which most functions use, is a collection of bits.  Files are read in bytes.  Your `writeBit` method writes bits not bytes.

If you really, truly, must write in bits, you will need to read in bytes, convert to bits and write each bit.  (By the way, most computers work better with larger units, such as bytes, and words.)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; // Because I'm lazy and this is an example.

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t byte;
// Open the file
//....

//  Read file as bytes.
    while (ifile.read(&byte, sizeof(byte)))
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0;
             i < CHAR_BIT; // number of bits in a byte
             ++i)
        {
            bos.writeBit(byte & 1);
            byte = byte >> 1;
        }
    }
//...
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There are faster ways to copy the contents of one file to another.  The first one that comes to mind is to let the OS do it.

**Edit 1: Analysis of the programs.**
The `BitOutputStream` class will accumulate the least significant bit of the integer passed to the `writeBit` method.  As soon as 8 bits are accumulated, the `writeBit` method writes a byte to the output stream.

In the first program, you are passing integers that have only one significant bit, or you are assuming that the integer constants have only one significant bit.

In the second program, you read in a byte (8 bits) via `istream::get()` method.  The `writeBit` method only looks at the least significant bit and places that bit into the `BitOutputStream` buffer. The loop then fetches another byte from the input file and only the least significant bit is appended to the `BitOutputStream` buffer.

After the 8th byte is read, the `BitOutputStream` buffer will have 8 bits and then an 8-bit byte is written to the stream.

So if I have a file with only an 'A' character, which is 0x41, or in binary MSB: 0100 0001.
The `writeBit` method ANDs the value with 0x1, with the result of 0x01 or a binary 1.  This bit is placed into the output buffer.  **THE REMAINING BITS OF THE BYTE ARE IGNORED** by `writeBit`.

When there is only 1 character, the `BitOutputStream` buffer has only 1 bit.  Also, your program never calls `BitOutputStream::flush()` so the partial bit is never output to the stream.  There is no destructor, so the incomplete byte (with only 1 bit) disappears when the `bos` object is destructed and nothing written to the output stream.

Since your second program passes a whole byte of 8 bits to a function that uses only 1 bit, I deduced that you have confused the concept of bits and bytes.  See my above code fragment that resolves your issue.

**Edit 2:  Testing the `BitOutputStream` class.**
The best process for testing this class is to derive your own class from `ostream`.  This class should have a method that you can pass an *expected* or *known* value to.  Pass an instance of this class to `BitOutputStream`.  The class's `put` method can compare the value from `BitOutputStream` to *expected* or *known* value.

Comment: I understand the difference between a bit and a byte also my first sentence should have said "bit by bit" instead of "byte by byte" which I edited. My class BitOutputStream does exactly what you described--read in bytes, converts them to bits and writes each bit, and this is exactly what I want. But when it comes to writing a tester I get mismatch in my input and output files and I was wondering why.

Comment: If you copy byte by byte, you are also copying bit by bit, unless I am missing some concept.

Comment: Without seeing the declaration and definition of BitOutputStream, I can't give you any more detailed help.

Comment: OK, I added it to the end of you answer, it seems to work for the first tester above but not the second.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @Napalidon - I moved the edit to your question instead of the end of the answer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Great, thanks for such a through analysis, now I understand where I went wrong, I assumed that get only got one bit for some reason.